# Lost files while moving to external USB flash drive

Tags: data-recovery

I was moving 50 files from my hard drive to an external USB stick. I removed the flash drive directly after the moving bar was complete but only 2 files were moved and the rest were lost. Is there any way to recover the lost files? I tried **TestDisk** but no files appear to be deleted neither from the source directory nor the destination directory.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I think there is no way to "recover" the files, because they haven't yet been actually written to your USB drive. You can't recover something that never was there in first place.
You should never remove USB drives before ejecting it via the file manager and before you get the message telling you that you can now remove the drive. Before this happens, the data is still in your computer's memory and mostly hasn't been written to the drive yet.

Comment: I used a program on Windows named **Easeus** and it recovered the data from the USB drive. 85% were recovered and the rest were permanently lost.

Comment: It's not the first time for me to encounter file copying/moving problems with Ubuntu. Is there any other safer way to copy/move files successfully from the first time? 
Thanks for replying!

Comment: Just remove the USB device in safe way, as it should be done. I never had any problems with copying to USB drives when properly unmounting the USB drive. You should **never** assume that you can just remove the drive after files **appear** to be copied. You should give a proper signal to the system that you want to remove the drive and wait until the system tells you it's safe to do so.